# Sentry.io on Next.Js + Serverless: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'webpack'

Tags: next.js, serverless-framework, sentry

After adding Sentry.io with the automatic wizard (it added `"@sentry/nextjs": "^6.11.0"` in `package.json`), I can't build my Next.js project anymore.

```
> npm run build
(...)
Error: Command failed with exit code 1: node_modules/.bin/next build
warn  - No ESLint configuration detected. Run next lint to begin setup
Failed to compile.
ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'webpack' in '/builds/group/project/web/node_modules/@next/react-refresh-utils'
(...)
info  - Using webpack 5. Reason: Enabled by default https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/webpack5
```

I tried to `npm install --save-dev webpack` but I'm running in other errors like

```
./node_modules/fsevents/fsevents.node
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
```

How can I fix this?

[EDIT]
I also use Serverless component `@sls-next/serverless-component@3.2.0` to deploy on AWS.
My next.config.js contains:

```
const moduleExports = { target: 'serverless' };
```

Comment: You could Tr deleting your node_modules folder and reinstalling dependencies, maybe something got mixed up

Comment: just tried but same error "Can't resolve 'webpack'"

Comment: Did it create or modify webpack, babel or ts configurations?

Answer (score 4):

Found. The problem was due to conflict with Serverless framework.

As described in https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/guides/nextjs/manual-setup/
[image]

I just added `useServerlessTraceTarget: true` to `serverless.yml`:

```
project:
  component: "@sls-next/serverless-component@3.2.0"
  inputs:
    useServerlessTraceTarget: true
    (...)
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Should I create a file called serverless.yml?

Answer (score 1):

Check the next.config.js file in the project root folder.

According to this guide, some changes are needed there, and maybe the wizard got it wrong: https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/guides/nextjs/manual-setup/

Post the file contents here for more help if needed.